# Scala Slick find all datetimes less than DateTime.now()

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I am trying to write a succinct Scala Slick query to find all date times that are less than the current `DateTime.now()`. I keep on getting compilation issues with `Column[DateTime]` not being comparable to a regular `DateTime`. What is the correct way to write this Scala Slick query?

The column definition is

```
def expirationTime = column[DateTime]("EXPIRATION_TIME")
```

and the query I am trying to write:

```
table.filter(_.expirationTime < DateTime.now())
```

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming that you are using the `lifted-embedding` with Silck.

So... Slick uses a concept called `lifted-embedding` where your Scala types are `lifted` ( changed into a more domain specific type ) using an approptiate `Rep` constructor to create a `lifted-representation` of your Scala type. Now for every column of type `Column[ T ]` is a sub-type of `Rep[ T ]` and a `TypedType[ T ]` must exist, which is `impliticty` required for any query.

Your specific `filter` query has following signature,

```
def filter[T](f: (E) ⇒ T)(implicit wt: CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, E.TableElementType]
```

Here, this implicit value `wt` of type `CanBeQueryCondition[T]` is a subtype of `( T ) => Column[ _ ]` and is used internally to lift ( convert ) your value of `type T` to `Column[ T ]`. So... you need to have a `implicit` instance of `CanBeQueryCondition[ DateTime ]` to be able to do this query.

Other than this, only following primitive types are supported out of the box for JDBC-based databases.

```
Numeric types: Byte, Short, Int, Long, BigDecimal, Float, Double
LOB types: java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Clob, Array[Byte]
Date types: java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp
Boolean
String
Unit
java.util.UUID
```

Which means... that you will have to use `java.sql.TimeStamp`.

Or you can write your own custom mapper which will provide all the boiler plate required for your `DataTime` column.

```
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile.MappedColumnType
import java.sql.Date
import org.joda.time.DateTime 

object MyCustomMappers {

  implicit def dateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Date] (
    { dateTime => new Date(dateTime.getMillis) },
    { date => new DateTime(date) }
  )

}
```

Now in your schema, you can just `import MyCustomMappers._` and then define columns  of `DateTime` type. Now you can do almost all that you can do with those built-in types.